# JSON Expectations for Ember Data Polymorphic Relationships

Tags: json, ember-data, polymorphic-associations

```
DEBUG:               Ember                     : 1.8.1
ember.js:15373DEBUG: Ember Data                : 1.0.0-beta.18
ember.js:15373DEBUG: Handlebars                : 1.3.0
ember.js:15373DEBUG: jQuery                    : 1.11.3
```

So I have a "Request" model which can depend on an account or other Requests that stand in for and account when it is  fulfilled.

I'm a bit confused about how to get the JSON right for Ember to pick this up.

On the server-side, ActiveModelSeriailzers seems to want to serialize polymorphic relationships like this:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "account_id" : { "id": 1, "type": "account"}
}
```

I have the following ED Models:

```
// abstract-account.js
export default DS.Model.extend();

//account.js
export default AbstractAccount.extend();

//request.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  account: DS.belongsTo('abstractAccount', { polymorphic: true} )
});
```

When I try to load the record using the default json, I get

```
Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` for account in an object passed to `push`
```

In my reading, I had gotten the impression that belongsTo polymorphic assocaitions should get sent like:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "account_id" : 1,
  "account_type" : "Account"
}
```

If I change the server to serialize like that, I instead get

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You may not pass `null` as id to the store's find method
```

I'm not really sure what I'm missing,or what the current recommended practice is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a similar setup with the first convention. Keep in mind Ember expects JSON objects to be namespaced under the class name, so for a GET to /requests you would need to return something like

```
{
    'requests': [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'account': { id: 10, type: 'account' }
        },
        {
          'id': 2,
          'account': { id: 20, type: 'some_other_abstract_account' }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is with the RESTAdapter declared in application/adapter.js, I haven't tried the ActiveModelAdapter. I have seen documents advising [another convention](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#polymorphic-relationships), but it's working for me with ember data 1.0.0-beta.16

Comment: I got it working when I did two things: 1. Stopped another serializer from sending way too many sideloaded records, which was messing with my new action's mojo, 2. Stopped using AMS polymorphic relationship and build json like you posted myself.